# I want my map to resize when the BottomSheet is expanded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a screen that has a map with a bottomSheet, my problem is that when I expand the bottomSheet, the whole map covers me, I need my map to resize depending on how much the bottomSheet expands

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        topBar = {
            AppTopAppBar(
                currentScreen = R.string.repartirExpedicion.string,
                username = vm.userName ?: ""
            )
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Text(text = "Hey")
            Text(text = "Hey")
            Text(text = "Hey")
            Text(text = "Hey")
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand() }
                }
            ) {
                Text("Collapse")
            }


        },
    ) { bottomSheetPaddings ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottomSheetPaddings), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Map(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
```

fun Map

```
    val southWest = LatLng(42.584177, -5.596355)
    val northEast = LatLng(42.613455, -5.564656)
    val bounds = LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast)

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(bounds.center, 14F)
    }
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = MapProperties(latLngBoundsForCameraTarget = bounds),
        onMapLoaded = {
            moveCameraToAdjustedBounds(scope, cameraPositionState, bounds)
        }
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = rememberMarkerState(position = northEast),
            title = "northEast",
            snippet = "northEast snippet",
        )
        Marker(
            state = rememberMarkerState(position = southWest),
            title = "southWest",
            snippet = "southWest snippet",
        )
    }
```

I have tried to listen to the changes of the composable with onSizeChanged, but when I expand the BottomSheet it does not enter through that block of code, I have tried it in the modifier of the bottomSheet, and inside the sheetContent, indicating a Column and with a modifier, but I don't know how do it